# VueJS - axios : "get" call does not seem to work

Tags: vue.js, axios

We are using VueJS to build an application, the axios "get" call to fetch the JSON output does not seem to get invoked. Tried to put variables to catch any error but they don't show anything either. "me.resp" gives the value TBD in the Vue component, so we know that execution reaches that point.

Please let us know what we might be doing wrong, appreciate your help.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

export const MY_CONST = 'Vue.js';
export let memberList = new Vue({
    el: '#members',
    data: {
        members: null,
        resp: null,
        error: "No"
    },

    mounted: function () {
        this.getAllMembers();
    },

    methods: {
        getAllMembers: function () {
            var me = this;
            try {
                me.resp = "TBD";
                axios.get("https://xxxxx.com/services/api.php")
                            .then(response => (me.resp = response))
                            .catch(error => (me.error = error));
            } catch (error) {
                me.error = "Some error";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you see the network call in your browser's network panel?

Comment: Yes I do and I see a fresh entry in the server log everytime I make the call. So it is hitting the server, but the response is not getting set into the object. "me.resp" is showing "TBD" as the value, not the response string from the call.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your code why you are not seeing the value being updated. I do however, see a bunch of superfluous code that isn't doing any work for you. Sometimes a tidy up can bring errors into focus.

The iffrst of these is your usage of  `var me = this` as a way of overcoming scoping issues in the axios callbacks. I see you are using es6 fat arrow functions in these callbacks. What is interesting about these is that they don't bind their own `this` context.

As a result, you should be able to do away with the `var me = this` and just write the callback as `response => this.resp = response`. While you are at it I would remove the superfluous `try catch`, since you are already catching in the promise chain. Result would look like:

```js
methods: {
  getAllMembers() {
    this.resp = "TBD";
    axios.get("https://etc")
      .then(res => this.resp = res)
      .catch(err => this.error = err)
  }
}
```

Note that usage of ES6 features is not supported in all browsers and might require transpilation using babel/webpack.

Hope this solves your issue! Otherwise try putting some print statements in the callbacks to see if they are invoked!

Comment: Thank you. I made the changes but still getting just "TBD" assigned to "this.resp" object. I see a fresh entry in the server log, so we know that the call went through. Issue seems to be about collecting the response.

Comment: methods: {
        getAllMembers: function () {
            this.resp = "TBD";
            axios.get("https://xxxx.com/services/api.php")
                .then(response => this.resp = response)
                .catch(error => (this.error = error));
        }

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be of CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing). It showed up in the Browser Console output and due to that the call was reaching the server but the response was not being given to the axios get method. I added the appropriate header in the PHP file and now it is fetching data. Thanks to those who took the effort to help.

Comment: Aah good old CORS can drive you mad. happy you found a solution!